# Windows console 'cl' compiling : execute vcvars64.bat every time?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, command-line, java-native-interface

I am trying to compile a C file in Windows console with 'cl'.
When I first tried this, It send a message like this :

```
fatal error C1083 : ... 'stdio.h' : No such file or Directory.
```

So I searched web and found some article execute vcvars64.bat and try again.
I followed that advise and it works nice. 
But whenever I reopen terminal it prints same error message what I had in very first time.

Should I execute vcvars64.bat every time, whenever I try to compile in Windows console?

PS.
My command was

```
cl Helloworld.c -Fehello.dll -MD -LD
```

Comment: If you have Visual Studio installed.. Just compile using the 'Visual Studio Command Prompt'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure a shortcut to invoke `cmd.exe` with a list of startup commands.  Create a shortcut to `cmd.exe`, then edit its "Shortcut->Target" in "Command Prompt Properties" to be `cmd.exe /K C:\path\to\file.cmd`.  Within `C:\path\to\file.cmd` you can put the call to invoke vcvars and any other setup you want to do every time.

Then you can invoke the shortcut instead of `cmd.exe` whenever you need to do command-line VS stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the problem in **vscode** that the integrated terminal cannot load the **vcvars**, causing the `torch.utils.cpp_extension.load` to crash.
I had to change in `launch.json` with `"console": "externalTerminal"` to use external terminal.
In the vscode setting of external terminal, set:

```
# Terminal > External: Windows Exec
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat & cmd.exe
```

This way, the external terminal is called with **vcvars** everytime.